# Canvas drawing is delayed after full Canvas bitmap fill

Tags: function, delphi, canvas, drawing, delay

This is a very strange problem, that I encountered today. I have two functions in a VCL forms application.

**1. function** - drawSobel() Fills an Image Canvas area with edges extracted from a Sobel algorithm. (there are no problems here)

**2. function** - drawLabels() After the first function, a function is called to add labels to the edges, that were just filled on the Canvas area.

**The problem:** - The second function is not fired, if called directly after the first one. I tried using **Sleep()** , but it seems, that Sleep does not delay one function, instead it delays all the draw actions executed in both functions.

```
//Here is the first function (drawing the edges of a sobel algorithm)

    procedure TForm1.drawSobel();
  var
  i, j: Integer;
  row: pRGBTriple ;
  bmp: TBitmap;
begin
      if Length(Img) > 0 then
      begin
        bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
        bmp.Width:=Length(Img);
        bmp.Height:=Length(Img[0]);
        bmp.PixelFormat:=pf24bit;
        for j := 0 to bmp.Height - 1 do
        begin
          row := bmp.ScanLine[j];
          for I := 0 to bmp.Width - 1 do
          if Img[i,j].sobel>0 then
            begin
              row[I].rgbtRed := 0;
              row[I].rgbtGreen := 0;
              row[I].rgbtBlue := 0;
            end
          else if Img[i,j].sobel<=0 then
            begin
              row[I].rgbtRed := 255;
              row[I].rgbtGreen := 255;
              row[I].rgbtBlue := 255;
            end
        end;
        Image1.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, bmp);
        bmp.Free;
      end;
  end;

//The second function, which doesn't fire

procedure TForm1.drawLabels();
var c:integer;
begin
   with Image1.Canvas do
  begin
       for c := 0 to High(obj_properties) do
     begin
        Image1.Canvas.Brush.Style:=bsClear;
        Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
        Canvas.MoveTo(obj_properties[c].x+5, obj_properties[c].y+5);
        Canvas.Font.Name := 'Arial';
        Canvas.Font.Style := [];
        Canvas.Font.Height := 14;
        Canvas.TextOut(Canvas.PenPos.X, Canvas.PenPos.Y, IntToStr(c+1));
     end;
  end;
end;

//Here are both functions executed.

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
drawSobel();
drawLabels();
end;
```

The only way this works is if the second function is triggered with a button click after the first one has been executed.

How should these functions be executed properly in a single button click function?

Comment: `Sleep()` doesn't help. It just gives you the same result in slower time. How about an SSCCE? Right now we have to guess at things like what types are involved, whether this is FMX or VCL and so on. It's much easier if we don't have to guess. If you provide an SSCCE, you'll get good answers.

Comment: The method is (almost) surely called. I think you just cannot see the expected result which may be caused by a wrong target canvas, empty `obj_properties` array, or e.g. wrong coordinates stored in that array. You will find your problem when you use debugger. For us it's impossible since we don't know any of these details.

Comment: @TLama , I guess that could be the case, since I can see flashes of the labels, when I click the button2Click very fast, but then it dissapears. Emm, didn't quite understand, where should I empty the array values exactly?

Comment: That's impossibe to say. First of all I would stop drawing on image component. Image controls should be used only for showing static images, nothing more. I would personally draw on a prepared bitmap and flush that bitmap on a paint box canvas when the system asks it to paint. In pseudo-code [`like this`](http://pastebin.com/Besmvvfp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Canvas` property used in your `TextOut` is the Form's, not that of Image1.

You change all the `Canvas.xxx` to `Image1.Canvas.xxx`.

Or change the `with` to `Image1,Canvas`  using a comma

Comment: Perhaps the X and Y are outside the size of the image?

Comment: Nope, the function executes properly if executed on a button click, but it does not execute right after the first function.

Comment: Anyway, remove "with" clause and check that drawing is on image

Comment: +1 This would appear to explain the problem. The lesson you should learn is to stop using `with`.